# Do I need a Visa or Passport to Visit the Caymans?

Tags: visas, passports, us-citizens, cayman-islands

I live in the USA. I’m an active SCUBA diver and have heard the Caymans have some amazing dive sites all around the islands.

I’ve been thinking about booking a trip down next year. Do I need a visa or passport to visit the islands?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: @NateEldredge American by birth

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't need a visa OR a passport. If you needed a visa, you would also need a passport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

US Citizens [don't need a visa](http://www.immigration.gov.ky/portal/page/portal/ver-16/immhome/visitinghere/visas/visitorsvisas/listofcountries/List_of_countries_02Oct_Final.pdf) and can enter without a passport provided they can show an original or notarised birth certificate to prove their citizenship, and that they have a return or through ticket to a country that will accept them. ([Source](http://www.immigration.gov.ky/portal/page/portal/immhome/visitinghere/passportexemptions))

Whilst it might be technically possible to fly without a passport, returning to the US with just a birth certificate might lead to delays at US immigration.

A passport is the way to go.

Comment: Timatic requires a US citizen to be holding a valid US passport to fly to the Caymans or to return to the US, so "A passport is the way to go" is correct. That means a US citizen, in the Caymans with only a birth certificate, would be refused boarding for any flight back to the US.

Comment: So it’s best, that if I go next year (hopefully the craziness has started to die down by then), it’s best to bring my passport to RETURN to the USA?

Comment: Do you have a passport? If so, why consider travelling without one? If not, get one. It's **the** document for international travel. You'll find using it easier than trying to persuade an airline clerk that your birth certificate is enough.

Comment: If you are not planning to travel outside the Western hemisphere in the near future, a **[Passport Card](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Passport_Card#:~:text=The%20United%20States%20passport%20card,such%20as%20domestic%20air%20travel.)** might be more convenient.

Comment: Correction: A Passport Card cannot be used for International Air Travel, only for Land or Sea borders in North America.

Answer (score 1):

As you are presumably a US resident, [you can stay for up to 30 days](http://www.immigration.gov.ky/portal/page/portal/immhome/visitinghere/passportexemptions):

> ## Residents of the United States of America
>
> A person resident in the United States of America who:
>
> - arrives in the Cayman Islands directly from that country;
> - on landing, produces a valid United States Alien Registration Card; and
> - produces a return or round trip ticket to that country,
>
> may be permitted to enter and remain in the Islands for a period not exceeding thirty days.

Comment: FYI: The "Alien Registration Card" is the so-called green card, issued to permanent residents.

Comment: Someone who lives in the US and asking about needing a passport is probably a US citizen, and won't have a Green Card. See my answer.